# How to query widgets attached to QLayout

Tags: python, pyqt

I would like to iterate through every widget attached to `HBoxLayout`.

```
    myLayout=QtGui.QHBoxLayout() 

    for i in range(myLayout.count()):
        print i
```

But I am getting an Attribute Error: `'QHBoxLayout' object has no attribute 'item'` on:

```
        item=self.ComboBoxQHBoxLayout.item(i)
```

What would be a proper syntax to query the widgets attached to layout using its index number?

Comment: Show fulle error message - there is number of line with problem - show this line and few lines before. It seems script has problem with some element like `myLayout.item`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the error states, layouts don't have `item`. However, they do have [`itemAt`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qboxlayout.html#itemAt) that returns `QLayoutItem`. You can get the widget out of `QLayoutItem` using [`widget()`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qlayoutitem.html#widget) method. If the item was not a widget (i.e. another layout or spacer) `None` will be returned.

```
for i in range(myLayout.count()):
    widget = myLayout.itemAt(i).widget()
    if widget:
        # item is a widget
        print widget
```